# what is the first parameter of presentOpenInMenuFromRect mean?

Tags: ios5

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *documentController;

-(void)openDocumentIn

{

    NSString *filepath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"Learn Book" ofType:@"pdf"];
    NSLog(@"path:%@", filepath);
    if(filepath == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"filepath is nil.");
        return ;
    }
    documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath]];
    documentController.delegate = self;
    documentController.UTI = @"com.adobe.pdf";
    CGRect navRect = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;
    navRect.size = CGSizeMake(1500.0f, 40.0f);
    [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:navRect inView:self.view animated:YES ];
    //[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES ];
}
```

I have change it from "CGRectZero" to "navRect",but dont see the difference after running. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter of ["`presentOpenInMenuFromRect`"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIDocumentInteractionController/presentOpenInMenuFromRect%3ainView%3aanimated%3a) is the location (in the coordinate system of *view*) at which to anchor the menu.

Doing "`CGRectZero`" won't work, because that means you're asking for a rectangle of zero height & width.  And doing the entire navigationBar (like what you did in "`navRect`" up there) isn't going to work either.

It's best to just set the rectangle to appear underneath or next to the button that fires off the `UIDocumentInteractionController`.